# Deleting a video from a playlist with YouTube Data API v3

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I'm building an application with which users can create playlists through drag and drop. I want them to be able to remove videos from a playlist. But I get confused with the docs.

I'm using the youtube api php client library. Keep in mind that the user is logged in.

```
$youtubeService = new Google_YouTubeService($client);
$playlistItems = $youtubeService->playlistItems;
$deleteVid = $playlistItems->delete($videocode);
```

And this is the delete function from the client library :

```
 /**
 * Deletes a playlist item. (playlistItems.delete)
 *
 * @param string $id The id parameter specifies the YouTube playlist item ID for the playlist item that is being deleted. In a playlistItem resource, the id property specifies the playlist item's ID.
 * @param array $optParams Optional parameters.
 */

public function delete($id, $optParams = array()) {
  $params = array('id' => $id);
  $params = array_merge($params, $optParams);
  $data = $this->__call('delete', array($params));
  return $data;
}
```

There's nowhere, where I can specify which playlist to delete the video from. Does anyone have an idea how to do this? The other playlistItem functions use a Google_PlaylistItem object as a parameter. But this one only a string for the videocode... So weird, can't figure this one out on my own.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PlaylistItemId is unique for the playlist. So same video in two different playlist has two diferent playlistitemId.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems

All you need to give is playlistitemId to that function, not the videoId.

You can find playlistitemId from [playlistItems->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) function specifying the playlist parameter.