# How to delete a video using the youtube API v3 and PHP

Tags: php, video, youtube, youtube-api

Just wondering how I would delete a video from YouTube using v3 of the API using the official Google PHP library.

I see this here:

[Deleting a video from a playlist with YouTube Data API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791792/deleting-a-video-from-a-playlist-with-youtube-data-api-v3)

```
$youtubeService = new Google_YouTubeService($client);
$playlistItems = $youtubeService->playlistItems;
$deleteVid = $playlistItems->delete($videocode);
```

Not sure if this is correct - does this work if the video is not in a playlist?

I also have the code for v2 of the API

[Deleting YouTube videos using Zend/PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501183/deleting-youtube-videos-using-zend-php)

```
$videoEntryToDelete = $yt->getVideoEntry($videoId, null, true);
$yt->delete($videoEntryToDelete);
```

But rather use v3

Comment: @James : Yes! finally (today). You need to use this line:  $youtube->videos->delete( $id ); where $youtube is your new instance of Google_Service_YouTube().

Comment: @James also the $id value is your video ID - just in case you were wondering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For those looking for the answer it was this:

```
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
...
//do your authoraisation stuff + getting access token etc
...
$youtube->videos->delete('<Your Video ID>');
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: how do i do my auth stuff and get an access token? can i just hard code them if i only want to do this for one youtube user? thanks

Comment: It seems that I can list channels in my account using my api key that i got from the dev console, but I cannot delete, i see this error: `(401) Login Required`